# create table from array with dynamic headers and data

Tags: php

I am trying to create a table from array retrieved from database.

array is multidimensional and dynamic.

my sample array is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => AmazonUK
        [totalCounts] => 2
        [netRoyalty] => 0.01006506
        [month] => 2017-05-01
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => AppleMusicGB
        [totalCounts] => 52
        [netRoyalty] => 43.39295886
        [month] => 2017-04-01
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => AppleMusicHK
        [totalCounts] => 2
        [netRoyalty] => 6.71799264
        [month] => 2017-05-01
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => AppleMusicIN
        [totalCounts] => 22
        [netRoyalty] => 1.29255252
        [month] => 2017-03-01
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => AppleMusicUS
        [totalCounts] => 192
        [netRoyalty] => 328.95685302
        [month] => 2017-03-01
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => Deezer
        [totalCounts] => 18
        [netRoyalty] => 2.91837036
        [month] => 2017-01-01
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => GoogleLocker
        [totalCounts] => 10
        [netRoyalty] => 0.08685774
        [month] => 2017-01-01
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => GoogleSubscription
        [totalCounts] => 30
        [netRoyalty] => 57.13748172
        [month] => 2017-03-01
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => Spotify
        [totalCounts] => 356
        [netRoyalty] => 179.53991898
        [month] => 2017-03-01
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => iTunesAU
        [totalCounts] => 14
        [netRoyalty] => 3.14949396
        [month] => 2017-02-01
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => iTunesCA
        [totalCounts] => 16
        [netRoyalty] => 0.18564444
        [month] => 2017-01-01
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => iTunesEU
        [totalCounts] => 4
        [netRoyalty] => 1.00737582
        [month] => 2017-02-01
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => iTunesGB
        [totalCounts] => 8
        [netRoyalty] => 0.91430508
        [month] => 2017-03-01
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [licensee] => iTunesUS
        [totalCounts] => 2
        [netRoyalty] => 99.69851988
        [month] => 2017-06-01
    )

)
```

I want to create a table like :

licensee as horizontal heading

month as vertical heading

totalCounts and netRoyalty as totalCounts/netRoyalty under their respective licensee

jsfiddle of sample table is included.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cv2c8f18/)

EDIT :

what i tried is

```
<table id="table1" class="table table-striped table-hover table-fw-widget">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <?php
                                foreach($distributorReportAnalysis as $distreportkey => $distreportval){
                              ?>
                                <th><?php echo $distreportval[licensee]; ?></th>
                              <?php
                                }
                              ?>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>

                          <tbody>
                          <?php
                            foreach($distributorReportAnalysis as $distreportk => $distreportv){
                          ?>
                            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                              <th><?php echo date('M Y',strtotime($distreportv[month])); ?></th>
                              <?php
                                foreach($distreportv as $reportk => $reportv){
                              ?>

                              <td><?php echo $distreportv['totalCounts']."/".round($distreportv['netRoyalty']); ?></td>
                              <?php 
                                }
                              ?>
                            </tr>
                          <?php 
                            }
                          ?>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: means you have to store something like your example in the database?

Comment: @dhaval-purohit no, data is already in database, i need to display it in table

Comment: you could use `array_map` for that, i guess that could be done too with more complex array functions, but array_map will be simple to use and readable

Comment: ok then first try to do it by your self. use your own logic and still things are not working then post that code here so we can help you out what you are doing wrong #stackoverflow is for finding and solving a problem not for doing your work by others.

Comment: @Kaddath can u provide any sample pls. thanks

Comment: @DhavalPurohit trying to figure it out from yesterday.... question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a quick example of how you could extract values with array_map. Actually a foreach works too, array_map is particularly useful if you want to modify the original array.
So the idea here is to organize the data before display, here getting the headers and value by month separately. For your display, you'll still have to place the good value to the good position in the array, but it is sorted by headers value now, so that will be easy.

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        0 => [
            'licensee' => 'AmazonUK',
            'totalCounts' => '2',
            'netRoyalty' => '0.01006506',
            'month' => '2017-05-01',
        ],

        1 => [
            'licensee' => 'AppleMusicGB',
            'totalCounts' => '52',
            'netRoyalty' => '43.39295886',
            'month' => '2017-04-01',
        ],
    ]; 

    $headers = [];
    $rows = [];

    function customExtract($element){
        global $headers, $rows;

        //an array for your headers
        if(!in_array($element['licensee'], $headers)){
            $headers[] = $element['licensee'];
        }

        //another for the rows by month
        if(!isset($rows[$element['month']])){
            $rows[$element['month']] = [];
        }
        $rows[$element['month']][$element['licensee']] = $element['totalCounts'] . '/' . $element['netRoyalty'];

        //you can also transform the original array element or not (if not you just return it)
        return $element;
    }

    $arr = array_map('customExtract', $arr);

    var_dump($headers);
    echo'<br />';
    var_dump($rows);
?>
```

the result:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "AmazonUK" [1]=> string(12) "AppleMusicGB" }
array(2) { ["2017-05-01"]=> array(1) { ["AmazonUK"]=> string(12) "2/0.01006506" } ["2017-04-01"]=> array(1) { ["AppleMusicGB"]=> string(14) "52/43.39295886" } }
```

Comment: thanks for the help... but steel i am not able to show it as table bcoz empty licensee is missing from new array.... tried to put missing licensee in array, but that will make all licensee value empty... any suggestion...

Comment: tried with this : foreach($rows as $rowsKey => $rowsVal){
 foreach($headers as $key => $val){
   if(!isset($rowsVal[$val])){
  $rows[$rowsKey][$val] = '';
   }else{
  $rows[$rowsKey][$val] = $rows[$rowsKey][$val];
   }
 }
  }

Comment: thank you for the solution.... problem solved... used ksort to sort array by value... thanks